# Why the MediaPlayer object is giving an exception?

Tags: android, exception, audio, media-player

This is my question about the exception which I am getting when I am playing an audio file. In my Jumbled words game app, I have two sound files, viz. clap.mp3 and oops.mp3. These files are played when the user provides a correct answer and wrong answer respectively. When the user provides the correct answer, the audio file clap.mp3 gets played and the user is provided with the next puzzle. Now when the user provides wrong answer to this puzzle, it should play oops.mp3. But my app, gives a ANR message that ask me to "Force Close" it. Please help me.

**Code:**

```
public void checkWord()
{
    if(abcd.equalsIgnoreCase(etGuessedWord.getText().toString()))
    {
        WordLibrary.setMyInt(WordLibrary.getMyInt() + 10);
        tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(WordLibrary.getMyInt()));
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap);
        mp.start();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(JumbledWords.this).setMessage("Awesome!!!") 
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            wordIdx = (wordIdx + 1) % getSize();
            sWord = getScrambledWord(word_list[wordIdx]);
            tvScrambledWord.setText(sWord);
            abcd = word_list[wordIdx];
            ++word_array_length;
            mp.stop();
            etGuessedWord.setText("");

            if(word_array_length >= word_list.length)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(JumbledWords.this).setMessage("Level Complete!!! ")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

                @Override 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    start = 0;
                    finish();           
                } 
                }).create().show();     
            }


        } 
        }).create().show();



    }
    else
    {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oop);
        mp.start();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(JumbledWords.this).setMessage("Wrong. Try Again")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            etGuessedWord.setText("");
        } 
        }).create().show();



    }
}


    etGuessedWord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(etGuessedWord.getText().toString().length() == abcd.length() )
            {
                checkWord();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

**Exception Message**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myambitionconsultants.JumbledWords.checkWord(JumbledWords.java:447)
at com.myambitionconsultants.JumbledWords$1.afterTextChanged(JumbledWords.java:125)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6281)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:6504)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:897)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:353)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:247)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's on (JumbledWords.java:447) ?

Comment: JumbledWords.java Line 447 mp.start();

Answer (score 0):

Hiiii,
Yor are getting null pointer exception means your MediaPlayer may not initialized.
so you have to initialize first. Are u initialize?
like, mp = new MediaPlayer(); after that u can use

Comment: Nope. I have tried to initialize using this statement:              mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap);
mp.start();

Answer (score 0):

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clap);
```

Returns null if the media player object creation failed. You should try using a different datasource like oops.mp3. This also could be a [device related](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4f93f48045ec4ce3/f1f14bef38e1e02b?lnk=gst&q=MediaPlayer.create#f1f14bef38e1e02b) problem.

Comment: No way 'coz, when the answer is correct clap.mp3 must get played. oop.mp3 will get played when the answer is wrong. I want both to get played at the right situation

Comment: I meant just for the sake of testing if clap.mp3 is a valid mp3 file that your phone can play.

Comment: I had done that too. If I ignore one of the mp3 files, it plays correctly.

Comment: The mp3 file which you are ignoring is corrupt or cannot be decoded by the mediaplayer.

Comment: Do i need both of them to convert from mp3 to ogg? 'Coz I have read somewhere that it is better to store the files in the ogg format in android phone.